# Does this customized bootstrap code need something that I'm missing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a passion project and going through the Bootstrap files and taking the things that I like, leaving out the stuff I don't like/need, and modifying the code so it fits my own personal style. I haven't gotten very far yet but this is something I need help with already that might be useful as I continue depending on how people help me out.

I'm working on the `.col-xs-*` section and I'm getting an issue like is shown below. Does anyone know why this is happening? None of the columns are spacing properly and I'm not sure why. I've used bootstrap in school for years and I don't actually know how it does what it does.

I'll try to post the code too that I've copied over already. So far I'm only working with pure CSS and I'm hoping this doesn't have to do with JavaScript stuff at this level but please let me know if what I'm missing is obvious.

```css
/* 
    The following stylesheet is an adaptation from Bootstrap and my own personal preferences.
    Most of the styles will be Bootstrap in structure but they will have only the parts that I want.
*/
.test {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/*********************************
COLORS

- Blacks
#141314 - Smoky Black
#1b1a1b - Eerie Black
#212021 - Raisin Black

- Greys/Silvers
#767676 - Sonic Silver
#949394 - Spanish Gray
#a8a8a8 - Silver Chalice

#5295bf - Carolina Blue
#991eeb - Purple X 11
#a31621 - Ruby Red
**********************************/

/*#region CUSTOM CSS FOR VISUALIZATION ONLY */

.container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col-visual [class*="col-xs-"] {
  background-color: #991eeb;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/*#endregion*/

/*#region COLORS */
/*#endregion*/

/*#region CONTAINER AND CONTAINER FLUID */
.container,
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

.container > .navbar-header,
.container-fluid > .navbar-header,
.container > .navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container > .navbar-header,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

/*Not sure if these are needed */
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.container:after,
.container-fluid:after {
  clear: both;
}
/*#endregion*/

/*#region ROW */
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

/* Not sure if these are needed */
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

/*#endregion*/

/*#region COLUMNS */
.col-xs-1,
.col-sm-1,
.col-md-1,
.col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-sm-2,
.col-md-2,
.col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-sm-3,
.col-md-3,
.col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-sm-4,
.col-md-4,
.col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-sm-6,
.col-md-6,
.col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-7,
.col-md-7,
.col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-sm-9,
.col-md-9,
.col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-sm-10,
.col-md-10,
.col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-sm-11,
.col-md-11,
.col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-12,
.col-md-12,
.col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

/*#endregion*/

/*#region EXTRA SMALL COLUMNS */
.col-xs-1,
.col-xs-2,
.col-xs-3,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-5,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-7,
.col-xs-8,
.col-xs-9,
.col-xs-10,
.col-xs-11,
.col-xs-12 {
  float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-xs-8 {
  width: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-7 {
  width: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-xs-5 {
  width: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}

/*#endregion*/

/*#region SWATCH (Color/image/icon tag thing) */
.swatch {
}

.swatch .swatch-content {
}

/*#endregion*/
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row col-visual">
    <h2>Columns Visualization</h2>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>COL-12</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <p>COL-11</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
      <p>COL-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <p>COL-10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <p>COL-2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <p>COL-9</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p>COL-3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <p>COL-8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>COL-4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <p>COL-7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <p>COL-5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>COL-6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p>COL-6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I left out the container and row stuff but here is everything. Again, sorry this is long. I'm just really not sure where to start when it comes to getting help with this. I guess I should also mention that I'm doing this through an angular project. Not sure that makes a difference. I just like how the components work.

**UPDATE**: I found that the columns are extending further than the container and its padding. I'm not sure how to fix this or how Bootstrap normally does this if someone could explain it to me?

**EDIT**: I updated the code snippet so it reflects my full project as is. I'm really not sure why this doesn't work properly. The blue line shows where the container border is and the columns still go past it. How do I get the columns to be a percentage wide in relation to the container and not the whole body?

Answer (score 0):

So I found my own answer. The problem I had was the attribute `box-sizing: border-box;` didn't exist on the different parts of the code. I found this by swapping the CSS from Bootstrap over my html and inspecting it. Simple solution, but a pain to track down and find.